# Simple batch script to check computer name in domain

Tags: windows, batch-file

Premise: I'm not a programmer.

I need to do a simple batch script that checks the computer name in domain and if it's the right name excute another batch script (I have already it) otherwise it check the next computer's name.

I trid to do something but it's very hard for me.

```
If %computername%=VDSXXXXXXD
   then c:\XXXXX\XXXX.bat
   echo VDSXXXXD FOUND
Else %computername%=VDSYYYYYD
     then c:\XXXXXX\ZZZ.bat
     echo VDYYYYYD FOUND
Else %computername%=VDSYYYYYD
     then c:\XXXXXX\ZZZZ.bat
     echo VDSZZZZZD FOUND
goto 
:End
```

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close for a non-programmer, this should work for you (though having a text file with all computer names would be optimal.)

```
If "%computername%"=="VDSXXXXXXD" (
start c:\XXXXX\XXXX.bat
echo VDSXXXXD FOUND
goto :eof
)
if "%computername%"=="VDSYYYYYD" (
start c:\XXXXXX\ZZZ.bat
echo VDYYYYYD FOUND
goto :eof
)
if "%computername%"=="VDSYYYYYD" (
start c:\XXXXXX\ZZZZ.bat
echo VDSZZZZZD FOUND
goto :eof
) 

:eof
Exit
```

And that should work for you fine,

Mona

Comment: thanks a lot for your quickly response. Before first if, HAve i to writhe something? like CLS?

Comment: You can add an `@echo off` as the first line to suppress echoing all of these lines to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and straight forward way of doing it.

If there is a relationship between the name and batch file then a loop would be easier to maintain.

```
@echo off
If %computername%=VDSXXXXXXD (echo VDSXXXXD FOUND & c:\XXXXX\XXXD.bat)
If %computername%=VDSXXXXXXE (echo VDSXXXXE FOUND & c:\XXXXX\XXXE.bat)
If %computername%=VDSXXXXXXF (echo VDSXXXXF FOUND & c:\XXXXX\XXXF.bat)
If %computername%=VDSXXXXXXG (echo VDSXXXXG FOUND & c:\XXXXX\XXXG.bat)
If %computername%=VDSXXXXXXH (echo VDSXXXXH FOUND & c:\XXXXX\XXXH.bat)
```

Comment: yes, there is a unique relationiship.For examples: The computer name: VDS00001D must necessarily run the script associated.

Comment: for each computer(trough the domain name) i must do run another script that which runs a specified command for a weighing system that we use in the company

Comment: Ok, but you haven't provided any further information to help with.  Do you have a list of the computernames in a text file?  Explain what you actually need to do.

Comment: yes i have a list in excel file. the total number of computer are 30. all computer are named VDS000XXD. And in the other batch file the script associates the computer name with the name of the matching scale.Then i want create a policy that run this script at  startup of the PC because in many case the final users creates problem